# Technical differences between PWA and Hybrid App

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, progressive-web-apps

What are the differences between a PWA and a hybrid app? This question was asked before but I haven't found found a proper answer to my question.

I know a PWA runs in the browser and you get a hybrid app from an app store.

But both are using JavaScript with HTML and CSS and both enable offline support and I can access native features like camera and local storage.

Once I have added a PWA to my Homescreen, it uses a web view to render the app right? And a hybrid app uses a web view as well, so what exactly are the differences between PWA and a hybrid app?

With Ionic I can even use the exact same code for a pwa and a hybrid app...

Comment: You cannot obtain Geolocation in the Background so no Geofences Location alerts etc. W3C and IETF flatly refuse to standardize this functionality even though the Service Worker hooks are ready and willing to go: - github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen see also github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/745

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roughly it is like this below:

- web app (PWA) is just a web-site that declares certain capabilities using manifest file etc which can get it some special treatments (like leverage service worker, sign up for web notifications, go full screen etc IF target browser supports it). As a web-app it is super limited in its "privileges" on a system level (like persistence quota etc)
- hybrid app (like Cordova for example) is a binary code that is "wrapping" your web-code and exposes certain "native" SDK capabilities via plugins. You can potentially also write your own plugin and in theory access any native SDK API this way. But since your main app code is still a web-app that runs inside of a webview it still has a lot of penalties like performance etc. But at least you can get things like storage etc.
- native app is a binary build using target platform's SDK. That in
  theory gives you max access to capabilities and performance at
  expense of having to write separate code for each platform.

Makes sense?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Progressive Apps

1. Today, these apps only work on Opera, Chrome, and the Samsung mobile browser. However, these browsers take up only less than half of the mobile browser market.
2. In some devices, some of the features will not work. For instance, notifications on iOS devices will not work.
3. In some apps, cameras, fingerprint scanner, and GPS may not work or work with glitches.

Cordova/ Ionic based hybrid apps

1. Making the hybrid apps run efficiently on multiple platforms is no easy task. In some instances, it could cost almost the same as running native apps. The cost will depend on how close you want to get to the native app experience.
2. Since these apps will launch using a browser-like component, they are only as good as the component on which they run. Earlier, Google and Apple did not agree on the WebView. While it has vastly been improved, it does not have the same efficiency as running a native app.